# bash function with return value AND return string

Tags: bash, function, return, echo

First my sourcecode to test the returning method of bash functions:

```
function oidev.fnc.bash.example.fncreturnstringvalue
{
  echo "ABC"
  return 1
}
```

and the caller function:

```
function oidev.fnc.bash.example.fncreturnstringvaluecaller
{
  local FNCVALUE
  local FNCSTRING
  FNCSTRING=$(oidev.fnc.bash.example.fncreturnstringvalue && FNCVALUE="$?" || FNCVALUE="$?")
   # String OK but Value empty
  echo "VALUE : $FNCVALUE" 
  echo "STRING: $FNCSTRING"
  unset FNCVALUE
  unset FNCSTRING
  oidev.fnc.bash.example.fncreturnstringvalue && FNCVALUE="$?" || FNCVALUE="$?"
    # Value OK and String on STDOUT
  echo "VALUE : $FNCVALUE" 
  echo "STRING: $FNCSTRING"
}
```

The output in bash:
    
VALUE :
    
STRING: ABC
    
ABC
    
VALUE : 1
    
STRING: (surely empty, but echoed from the function)
`


And now my simple question:

Is it possible to get the returning string and returning value into two different variables by a single line construction?

I don't want to use globals, nore the use of if $? after the sub-call!

Many thanks for help, and sorry for my german-english!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, maybe helps:

```
func() {
    echo 'abc'
    return 111
}

read var1 var2 <<<$(func; echo $?)
echo "var1 $var1"
echo "var2 $var2"
```

will print:

```
var1 abc
var2 111
```

workaround for the "spaces problem" - now, haven't better idea as use an helper function like this

```
func() {
    echo 'abc def'
    return 111
}

runner() {
    ret=$(func)
    echo $? $ret
}

read -r var2 var1 <<<$(runner func)
echo "var1 $var1"
echo "var2 $var2"
```

or using a helper variable and switching the variable order

```
func() {
    echo 'abc def'
    return 111
}
read -r var2 var1 <<<$(res=$(func); echo $? $res)
echo "var1 $var1"
echo "var2 $var2"
```

both will return

```
var1 abc def
var2 111
```

Comment: Thanks for this perfect answer, the <<< construction..., google knows!

Comment: This will not work if the string returned by `func()` contains spaces.

Comment: Yes, but it can be quoted inside the function with echo "\'a b c\'"  to one variable to READ from the Caller

Comment: two statements. `var1=$(func); var2=$?`

Comment: @KlausBaumann `read` splits based on `IFS`. quotes don't matter unless you put quotes in `IFS`

Comment: Yes, I tried to "read -a" and it splits all echos into the array with the strings seperated by IFS and the well defined "last element" return value (First step OK)! Now, but no more today (00:25) my aim is to find a way (maybe IFS) to get back all the sub-function-echos into a caller string unchanged! ...